# Pyspark: to_date and unix_timestamp return null for some records for others valid values

Tags: time, pyspark, formatting, unix-timestamp, to-date

The above command is giving null for few records.
Can anyone please tell what might be the reason for this. I have tried using to_date and unix_timestamp function but both are giving the same result ( null for few values).

```
date_cols.withColumn('date_timestamp',unix_timestamp('Date',"M/dd/y HH:mm:ss a")).show(truncate=False)


|----------------------|----------------------|--------------|
|Date                  |Updated On            |date_timestamp|
|----------------------|----------------------|--------------|
|02/05/2018 01:10:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|1517793000    |
|01/23/2018 09:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|1516698000    |
|01/31/2018 10:12:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|1517393520    |
|02/01/2018 02:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|01/27/2018 09:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|02/02/2018 12:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|1517572800    |
|01/28/2018 07:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|01/10/2018 04:45:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|01/03/2018 03:45:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|02/04/2018 04:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|01/27/2018 07:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|1517036400    |
|02/05/2018 12:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|01/21/2018 02:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|1516500000    |
|02/02/2018 12:45:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|01/25/2018 01:14:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|02/05/2018 05:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|01/15/2018 12:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|02/05/2018 07:30:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|02/02/2018 08:30:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
|02/03/2018 06:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|null          |
+----------------------+----------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was making one small mistake, and after looking into the [doc][1]

it got resolved, so posting here, it might help someone.
[1]: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html

have to use **hh** instead of **HH** while formatting. As **hh** represents **clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)** while **HH** represents **hour-of-day (0-23)**

```
date_cols.withColumn('date_timestamp',unix_timestamp('Date',"MM/dd/y hh:mm:ss a").cast(TimestampType())).show(truncate=False)

|----------------------|----------------------|-------------------|
|Date                  |Updated On            |date_timestamp     |
|----------------------|----------------------|-------------------|
|02/05/2018 01:10:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-05 01:10:00|
|01/23/2018 09:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-23 09:00:00|
|01/31/2018 10:12:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-31 10:12:00|
|02/01/2018 02:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-01 14:00:00|
|01/27/2018 09:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-27 21:00:00|
|02/02/2018 12:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-02 12:00:00|
|01/28/2018 07:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-28 19:00:00|
|01/10/2018 04:45:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-10 16:45:00|
|01/03/2018 03:45:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-03 15:45:00|
|02/04/2018 04:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-04 16:00:00|
|01/27/2018 07:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-27 07:00:00|
|02/05/2018 12:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-05 00:00:00|
|01/21/2018 02:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-21 02:00:00|
|02/02/2018 12:45:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-02 00:45:00|
|01/25/2018 01:14:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-25 13:14:00|
|02/05/2018 05:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-05 17:00:00|
|01/15/2018 12:00:00 AM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-01-15 00:00:00|
|02/05/2018 07:30:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-05 19:30:00|
|02/02/2018 08:30:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-02 20:30:00|
|02/03/2018 06:00:00 PM|02/12/2018 03:49:14 PM|2018-02-03 18:00:00|
|----------------------|----------------------|-------------------|
```